# Do the restartable sequence jobs in datastage also rerun the job activities that were aborted not because of sequence faliure

Tags: sequence, jobs, datastage

I want to know that whether the restartable sequence jobs in datastage also rerun the job activities that were aborted but not due to the sequence failure?

Answer (score 0):

In the Job Properties of a Sequence, in the 'General' Tab, you can activate "Add checkpoints so sequence is restartable on failure."
If a sequence is made restartable, the subsequent jobs are each getting a checkpoint.

When running the sequence the first time, it records which jobs have sucessfully finished. If the sequence is restarted, no matter for what reason it aborted before, the sequence will just skip the jobs that have been sucessful in the previous run.

If you need to have a job executed each time, even if it was already successful the last time, you can disable checkpinting for that job in the "Job" tab of it's Job Activity stage by checkiing the checkbox "Do not checkpoint run."

Comment: To improve the answer, you may want to suggest how to disable checkpointing and provide your answer in more visual form. It would aid it comprehension.

Comment: @JasonK. Thank you for the feedback. i gave it a retry.

Answer (score 0):

I think Justus's answer is right, but with a slight deviation:-

I found out that if a parallel job has aborted anywhere in a sequence, then it's rerun will be attempted by the controller (if the job activity is set to reset if required then run). (If we resume the sequence from Aborted/Restartable) or (Stopped/Restartable) state.

For example:-

let's say the job flow is as below:

```
a -> b -> c -> d -> e
```

if sequence is run and
job 'a' is finished,
job 'b' is aborted,
job 'c' is aborted, and the sequence stops due to user intervention,

Then if checkpointing is enabled earlier, our sequence, when restarted, will ignore job 'a' (already checkpointed) and rerun job 'b' and then job 'c' and the flow will resume.